# GCP Terraform error creating multiple VMs from Instance Template with "additional_disks"

Tags: templates, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a requirement to create multiple VMs in GCP using the Instance Template module located here:
https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-vm/tree/master/modules/instance_template

My Instance Template code looks like this:

```
module "db_template" {
  source               = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
  version              = "7.8.0"
  name_prefix          = "${var.project_short_name}-db-template"
  machine_type         = var.app_machine_type
  disk_size_gb         = 20
  source_image         = "debian-10-buster-v20220719"
  source_image_family  = "debian-10"
  source_image_project = "debian-cloud"
  
  additional_disks     = var.additional_disks
  labels = {
    costing   = "db",
    inventory = "gcp",
  }
  network       = var.network
  subnetwork    = var.subnetwork
  access_config = []
  service_account = {
    email  = var.service_account_email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
  tags = ["compute"]
}
```

in my tfvars I have this:

```
additional_disks = [
    { disk_name     = "persistent-disk-1"
      device_name   = "persistent-disk-1"
      auto_delete   = true
      boot          = false
      disk_size_gb  = 50
      disk_type     = "pd-standard"
      interface     = "SCSI"
      disk_labels   = {}
    }
]
```

However when my code has multiple VMs to deploy with this template, only 1 VM gets deployed--the first--and the subsequent VMs error out with this message:

```
Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 409: The resource 'projects/<PATH>/persistent-disk-1' already exists, alreadyExists
```

I understand what is happening but I don't know how to fix it. The subsequent VMs cannot be created because the `additional_disk` name has already been taken by the first VM. I thought the whole point of using the instance template would be that there is logic built into this where you can use the same template and create multiple VMs of that type.

But it seems like I have to do some additional coding to get multiple VMs deployed with this template.

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: And how are you trying to deploy multiple instances?

Comment: Use something like `disk_name = "$disk-{random_id.id.hex}"` https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/id

Comment: That would have to be a different variable and written differently, but that is a good idea.

Comment: I should have mentioned my method for scaling the instances was `for_each`, which might have influenced your comments. I did try various incarnations of the `random_id` resource, but also found scaling hard to do with that. Ultimately I got it working with `for_each` and creating and attaching the disks in two moves.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately got this working with various `for_each` constructs:

```
locals {
  app_servers = ["inbox", "batch", "transfer", "tools", "elastic", "artemis"]
  db_servers  =  ["inboxdb", "batchdb", "transferdb", "gatewaydb", "artemisdb"]
}

resource "google_compute_disk" "db_add_disk" {
  for_each = toset(local.db_servers)
  name  = "${each.value}-additional-disk"
  type  = "pd-standard" // pd-ssd
  zone  = var.zone
  size  = 50
  // interface     = "SCSI"
  labels = {
    environment = "dev"
  }
  physical_block_size_bytes = 4096
}
module "db_template" {
  source               = "terraform-google-modules/vm/google//modules/instance_template"
  version              = "7.8.0"
  name_prefix          = "${var.project_short_name}-db-template"
  machine_type         = var.app_machine_type
  disk_size_gb         = 20
  source_image         = "debian-10-buster-v20220719"
  source_image_family  = "debian-10"
  source_image_project = "debian-cloud"
  

  labels = {
    costing   = "db",
    inventory = "gcp",
  }
  network       = var.network
  subnetwork    = var.subnetwork
  access_config = []
  service_account = {
    email  = var.service_account_email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }
  tags = ["compute"]
}

resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "db_server-1" {
  for_each =  toset(local.db_servers)
  name = "${var.project_short_name}-${each.value}-1"
  zone = var.zone

  source_instance_template =  module.db_template.self_link
 

  // Override fields from instance template
  labels = {
    costing   = "db",
    inventory = "gcp",
    component = "${each.value}"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_attached_disk" "db_add_disk" {
  for_each = toset(local.db_servers)
  disk     = google_compute_disk.db_add_disk[each.key].id
  instance = google_compute_instance_from_template.db_server-1[each.key].id
}
```